# How do I make a QML rectangle spawn?

Tags: javascript, qml

I'm currently making a game called Snowflake to learn how to program QML with Javascript.

- I have my sourcecode here: https://gist.github.com/4510190.

The only files i got besides that is a default qmlproject file and a png file.

I have made this timer(Timer) and a rectangle(skullflake) which it should spawn for every interval it has finished.

```
Timer { //spawnrate
         interval: 2000; running: true; repeat: true
         onTriggered: Qt.createQmlObject(skullflake)
     }
```

But when I try to run it, it gives me the error:

> file:///where/the/project/is/saved/Snowflake/Snowflake.qml:21: Error: Qt.createQmlObject(): Invalid arguments

I have tried with both these elements but I can't seem to make it work

> - Qt.createComponent(skullflake)
> - Qt.createQmlObject(skullflake)

Comment: Well after I posted this I figured it out ;P

Comment: You could answer your own question and accept it, so others may see the solution if they search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using wrong Qt.createQmlComponent().
It requires 3 parameters:

```
Qt::createQmlObject ( string qml, object parent, string filepath )
```

So it should look like something like this (parent should be id of element which should contain skullflake):

```
Timer { //spawnrate
         interval: 2000; running: true; repeat: true
         onTriggered: Qt.createQmlObject("YOUR skullflake QML CODE (NOT FILE PATH)", parent, "skullflake")
     }
```

Comment: I pretty much think you need the answer here :)

Comment: Thanks :) I just tried to explain why code in question didn't worked. Good luck with your game.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the [Qt.createComponents()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qml-qt.html#createComponent-method) which requires you to use a QML file on the side or use the Component element.

```
 Item {
 id: container
 width: 300; height: 300

 function skullFlake() {
     var component = Qt.createComponent("Skullflake.qml");
     if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
         var flake = component.createObject(container);
         flake.color = "purple";
     }
 }

 Component.onCompleted: loadButton()
}

Timer { //spawnrate
     interval: 2000; running: true; repeat: true
     onTriggered: skullFlake();
}
```

Comment: If your QML file is stored locally, you actually don't need "if (component.status == Component.Ready) {", this is only used for asynchronous remote file loading (via network).